# Different versions of Swift giving me errors

Tags: swift, xcode, version, mp3, avaudioplayer

So I've been watching a lot of youtube videos and currently it seems 
like there is a huge disconnect between one version of Swift and another. 
I have literally looked at it line for line... character by character and 
an exact duplicate gives me errors like

> Errors thrown from here are not handled

and

> Variable Declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body.

I was trying to make a button play an MP3... found a good tutorial but I finished writing the code and it gave me a bunch of errors...

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        if let player = player, player.isPlaying{
            // stop playback

            player.stop()
        }
        else{
            // set up player and play
            let urlString =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "30 Minute Hockey Mix", ofType: ",m4a")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: . notifyOthersOnDeactivation)


                guard let urlString = urlString else {
                    return
                }

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))

                guard let player = player else {
                    return


                        player.play()

                }
                catch do {
                    print("Error You dumbass")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I’m assuming you didn’t mean to include that comma in the file extension `",m4a"`.

Answer (score 1):

You just messed up by not having a } after your return, so the do and try no longer matched up.  One thing I've noticed in swift, is when I suddenly have a whole bunch of errors, it is almost always a missed } placement.  It makes all the things after it really confuse the compiler.

```
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: . notifyOthersOnDeactivation)


            guard let urlString = urlString else {
                return
            }

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))

            guard let player = player else {
                return
            }

            player.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error You dumbass")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that one of your braces is in the wrong place.

It should be like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
            // stop playback

            player.stop()
        } else {
            // set up player and play
            let urlString =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "30 Minute Hockey Mix", ofType: "m4a")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

                guard let urlString = urlString else {
                    return
                }

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))

                guard let player = player else {
                    return player.play()
                }
            } // add this
            catch {
                print("Error", error)
            }
        // } remove this
        }
    }
}
```

If you select your code (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or choose “Editor” » “Structure” » “Re-Indent”, it will format your code, making it easier to see where the misplaced braces are.

Anyway, that solves the “Errors thrown from here are not handled” error.

The second error, the “Variable Declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body” is a result of this code:

```
guard let player = player else {
    return player.play()
}
```

That doesn’t make sense. That’s saying “if I can’t unwrap `player`, then `return` it”. Perhaps you meant:

```
if let player = player {
    player.play()
}
```

Or, more simply, you can use optional chaining, which achieves the same thing more concisely:

```
player?.play()
```

Thus:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
            // stop playback

            player.stop()
        }
        else{
            // set up player and play
            let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "30 Minute Hockey Mix", ofType: "m4a")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

                guard let urlString = urlString else {
                    return
                }

                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))

                player?.play()
            } catch {
                print("Error", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I might simplify this further:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
            // stop playback

            player.stop()
            return
        }

        // set up player and play
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "30 Minute Hockey Mix", withExtension: "m4a") else {
            return
        }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            player?.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error", error)
        }
    }
}
```